# Visual Studio 2010 toolbox buttons grow when I move mouse over

Tags: visual-studio-2010, zooming

For some reason when I go over with the mouse on the buttons in toolbox they grow up and I cannot cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Visual Studio 2010, you dont have another solution.

Comment: Its only on one of my solutions

Comment: Well, then I don't know, You must have done something to cause it. Try to click on Window--->Reset Window Layout that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your tool box

May be solve your problem